# Как прочитать файл на компьютере

Tags: java

У меня есть `Skulls.txt` документ, мне нужно читать его на компьютере а не на сайте.

Пробовал так:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(new URL("http://test.com/a/Skulls.txt").openStream());
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    this.list.add(s.nextLine());
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Непонятно. Если файл находится на сайте, как вы собираетесь читать его на компьютере?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Фамилия Я дописал пример кода для чтения файла его надо переделать для чтения файла с компьютера

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/newScannerFileReaderfile.htm

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо